# Manual buttoncommand binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom `DataGridColumn` that creates controls manually for editmode like so

```
public class DataGridLookupColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var dataGridBoundColumn = cell.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;

        var dockPanel = new DockPanel { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };

        var textbox = new TextBox { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };
        var button = new Button { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };

        DockPanel.SetDock(button, Dock.Right);

        dockPanel.Children.Add(button);
        dockPanel.Children.Add(textbox);

        textbox.Style = cell.FindResource("TextboxWithoutRoundedCorners") as Style;
        button.Style = cell.FindResource("LookupButtonRed") as Style;

        if (dataGridBoundColumn != null)
        {
            var cellContent = cell.Content as TextBlock;
            var bindingExpression = cellContent != null ? BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(cellContent, TextBlock.TextProperty) : null;

            if (bindingExpression != null)
            {
                BindLookupCommand(bindingExpression, button);

                var newBindning = new Binding(bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path.Path)
                {
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger,
                    Mode = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Mode
                };

                textbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, newBindning);
            }
        }

        return dockPanel;
    }

    private void BindLookupCommand(BindingExpression bindingExpression, Button target)
    {
        ICommand lookupCommand;

        if (CommandList.TryGetValue(bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path.Path, out lookupCommand))
        {
            var bindning = new CommandBinding(lookupCommand);
            target.CommandBindings.Add(bindning);
            target.Command = lookupCommand;
        }

    }

    public Dictionary<string, ICommand> CommandList { get; set; } 
}
```

As soon as i set the `CommandProperty` of the `Button` cant be clicked anymore. Is there anything else i need to do to get the binding to work?

I have verified that i get the correct `CommandObject`.

Thanks

Comment: does your command implement canexecute?

Comment: so can you put breakpoint in your canexecute and check if it returns false for your command... that is the reason why your button is disabled

Comment: one more thing thats wierd is that when i click over the button i come out of editmode into viewmode again of the gridcolumn. Its not that i cant click it.